# How to wait for image load from ajax() success data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have jquery `ajax()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'url='+variable,
    success: function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

My ajax response (`data` variable) is similar to this:

```
<a id="90" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink90.jpg" /></a>
<a id="91" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink91.jpg" /></a>
<a id="92" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink92.jpg" /></a>
<a id="93" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink93.jpg" /></a>
<a id="94" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink94.jpg" /></a>
<a id="97" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink97.jpg" /></a>
<a id="98" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink98.jpg" /></a>
<a id="120" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink120.jpg" /></a>
<a id="121" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink121.jpg" /></a>
<a id="122" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink122.jpg" /></a>
<a id="123" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink123.jpg" /></a>
<a id="124" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink124.jpg" /></a>
<a id="125" href="mylink"><img src="myimagelink125.jpg" /></a>
```

So my question is: what's the easiest way to wait for myimagelink#.jpg are all loaded?

Comment: What do you want to do while you 'wait'

Comment: jQuery waits for no man.

Comment: there will be preloader but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `load()` function. In this case, you'll need to bind it using the `live()` handler, as the images are dynamically being loaded:

```
var loaded = 0;

$('#mydiv a img').live('load', function()
{
  loaded++;

  if (loaded == $('#mydiv a img').length)
  {
    alert('All of the images have loaded.');
  }
});
```

There might be a more efficient way to do this, so feel free to say how slow this might work.

Comment: Since the HTML is appened using ajax usage of live is more applicable.

Comment: this solution looks great but the live event doesn't fire and I have no idea why. $('#mydiv a img').length) returns proper value. On `success:` I set `loaded` to 0 and use `html()` to set `data` to my div

Comment: ok, I have probably solved it. I replaced `live('load',...` with `load(,...` ; I just don't understand why live() didn't work

Comment: Huh, that's odd. `.load` shouldn't be firing, but if it works, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put an "onload" event on each, increment some counter and see if it matches the number of images you've inserted.

Comment: Heh, that seems pretty similar to what I did ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the images dinamically, and want to display after they load?

While 'data' is a javascript variable that contains the strings, your images ain't going to load...

To load the images before inserting them to the page, you'll have to make them dom elements.

Don't know if it's the best option, but i think this works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'url='+variable,
    success: function(data){
        $('<div />').html(data).load(function(){
            $(this).appendTo("#myDiv");
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: "url=" + variable,
  async: true,
  beforeSend : function(){
    $("#Loading").show(); //show image loading
  },
  success: function(msg){
    $("#LoadingPiloto").hide(); //hide image loading
  }
})
```